# Inject javascript into a page from a feature

Tags: javascript, feature

I want to add a verb (link in the top left menu of a web part) to all the web parts in Sharepoint 2010. Is there a way to inject javascript into a all the pages from a custom feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom control that uses the SharePoint scriptlink control and furthers registers your JS file using the ScriptLink.Register method on the page.

Next you can deploy this custom control as a delegate control. You can use any existing delegate control like AdditionalPageHead inside the master page or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

somehow injecting javascript into all the pages just sounds like a bad idea, you could however alter the master page to include a javascript file and deploy the updated master page as part of the feature.

Comment: This sounds good, but what if the user has customized his master page already? I will overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to add your action as a webpart verb?

Is Ribbon UI or a Site Action acceptable?

[How to: Modify the User Interface Using Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473643.aspx)

This series of articles goes into more depth.

[Customizing Ribbon UI - Part 1](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html)

Comment: This new verb will perform and action based on the content of the web part. So, I need a way to know which web part the user wants to perform this action on. I think I can use a ribbon button or site action as long as there is a way of knowing the specific web part.

Comment: Ribbon UI can interact with the currently selected webpart.