# What different ways can jQuery be added to SharePoint Sites?

Tags: 2013, development

As the question states, What different ways can jQuery be added to SharePoint?

Lets say that we have deployed jQuery to SharePoint.

We can add it through:

- Master Page.
- Adding it to a new Site through a Feature Event Receiver.

Question:

Can jQuery be added with JavaScript? If YES, would a good way to do this, to have a `addJQuery.js` file that can be included in the JS-Link property?

What other ways are available?

Answer (score 4):

You could also link it through a Custom Action. You can find more information about this approach at http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2010/03/01/scriptsrc-referencing-javascript-files-with-sharepoint-2010-custom-actions.aspx

Comment: Custom action is probably the most sustainable model (thinking about the app model)

Answer (score 2):

You can add Jquery refernce directly to the master as it will required on many pages.

Following links will help you how to add this:

[How to add JQuery library in SharePoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91981/how-to-add-jquery-library-in-sharepoint2013)

[Adding jQuery to master page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86979/adding-jquery-to-master-page)

Comment: Well lets say i can't touch the masterpage. What other ways arr available?

Comment: From feature you can add javascript file to site. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6180/inject-javascript-into-a-page-from-a-feature